# How to find out what debug symbol means

Tags: java, linux, performance, jvm

I'm profiling Java (`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)`) application that mostly consists of `I/O` file to socket. The data is read from a file, gzipped on the fly and send to a socket.

I did some cpu-cycles sampling with perf and got the following picture:

[image]

The thing I noticed was `sys_futex` consumes most of the CPU (percisely `_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore` - 11.44%) and the so called `_ZN12GCTaskThread3runEnv` symbol which I guessed from its name is related to `GC`.

***QUESTIONS:***

1. How to find out what this symbol `_ZN12GCTaskThread3runEnv` is responsible for?
2. Why is the `futex`es (`futex_wait`, `futex_wake`) are the most cpu-time consuming? I expected that sort of `copy_user_enhanced_fast_string` due to high `I/O` activity would be on top, but it takes only `0.56%` in the samples shown.

AFAIK `_raw_spin_unlock_irqstore` stands for waiting on I/O event, but why does it comsume more CPU than the I/O itself?

Comment: Is this interesting? [Java periodically hangs at futex and very low IO output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262946/java-periodically-hangs-at-futex-and-very-low-io-output)

Comment: @rghome The thing is the application I'm profiling does not hang periodically. It works this way constantly consuming too many cpu time on futex.

Comment: Use [demangler](https://demangler.com/) to translate `_ZNxxx` symbols to readable C++ identifiers.

Comment: @apangin Very useful, did not know about that. Thanks much!

Comment: @apangin Do you have any idea of how to figure out where the futexes come from? Maybe `async-profiler` can filter out events to show only "futex"-related traces?

Comment: Sure. try `-e syscalls:sys_enter_futex`. Or just use regular cpu profiling - if `sys_futex` is a hot function, it will definitely appear in the profile.

Comment: @apangin Is it a common approach to ignore SEGV when debugging with gdb (in this case I wanted to trace which tasks are actually returned by `GCTaskManager::get_task(uint)` and what `GCTask::do_it` actually does), but jvm always segfaults untill I ignored segv.

Comment: HotSpot uses signals for [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250235/exception-0xc0000005-from-jni-createjavavm-jvm-dll/36258856#36258856). So yes, ignoring them in gdb is OK.