# Spyder hangs on calling random.uniform()

Tags: python, winapi, random, spyder

My program frequently access random numbers. I initiate my random number generator via:

```
import random
random.seed(1)
```

I'm calling `random.uniform()` a lot in code for an evoluationary model (biology) and it repeatidly hangs (doing nothing for 20 minutes and then I stop it) after a while. While it hangs Python is using my CPU with 20%-30% (I have four cores). At the same time it's using 10GB Ram (I am having a lot of data).

Can I do something to make the default random library not hang or is there another random libary I can use?

I'm running Spyder 4.2.5 with Python 3.8 on Windows 10. (The problem already existed with an earlier version of Spyder and I installed Spyder 4.2.5 from skretch)

Comment: are you using random from a thread? does it behave this way if you disable the pagefile? heavy-handed, but does using a more science-oriented operating system help?

Answer (score 1):

Just speculating, but the default `random` module definitely shouldn't do that, so I suspect either

- there's something wrong with your Python install itself
- your system doesn't have enough entropy (or you are exhausting the pool by making a massive number of sequential calls to it, rather than simply using the base value) and is relying on /dev/random (which blocks until data is available) .. see related

  - [differences between random and urandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712581/differences-between-random-and-urandom)
  - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0524/

Try calling `os.random` with and without the blocking flag

```py
import os
os.getrandom(1024, flags=os.GRND_NONBLOCK)  # raise for low entropy
```