# How to fill a certain amount of RAM with the output of /dev/random?

Tags: bash, shell, random, ram

The following command line can be used to allocate an arbitrary amount of memory, e.g. 1GB. The memory area is filled with zeros.

```
</dev/zero head -c $((1024**3)) | tail
```

However, how can you similarly fill a given amount of memory, e.g. 1GB, with random numbers?

Contrary to expectations, the two following variants do not lead to a selectable allocation size of the working memory, but to an output of a few hundred random characters in the terminal:

```
</dev/random head -c $((1024**3)) | tail
```

The follow one are looks not like a solution, because its manipulate the data (remove/0) and it save only some hundred caracters var, but not 1GB:

```
output=$(sudo head -c $((1024**3)) /dev/random | tr -d '\0' | tail)
```

About the follow one can be possible a idea for a solution, but its looks like it only some hundred caracters on var and not 1GB:

```
output=""
while IFS= read -r -d '' substring; do
 output+="$substring"
done < <(sudo head -c $((1024**3)) /dev/random | tail)
```

Comment: `tail` only shows the last few lines of its input. For `/dev/zero` that will be the entire input, since there are no newlines in the input. Random input will have newlines, though. Pipe the input to something that will keep the entire input in memory rather than `tail`.

Comment: @John Kugelman Ahh thanks, so I could also send the data to a variable held in memory.

Comment: Shell variables can't hold `\0` bytes.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Well -- not _string_ variables, but you could use `readarray -d '' < <(dd ...)` to populate an array.

Comment: That said, our topicality guidelines have a requirement that questions be _practical_ in nature (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). What's the practical goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: (Also, if we know _why_ the OP wants to populate memory with random data, we'll have a better sense of how random it needs to be; perhaps base64-encoded or uuencoded data without any NULs would be fine).

Comment: (...for that matter, right now without knowing the "why" we don't know if it's virtual memory or physical memory that needs to be filled; if it's the latter, bash might be a completely unsuitable programming language for the job in the first place, as `mlock()` isn't accessible from bash without writing a C extension).

Comment: @Charles Duffy, filling memory by /dev/random sounds for me like more real data than filling the memory by /dev/zero/ Thats make a diffrent, p.e. if the system use a compression algo in the background. If its a different for the solution, so fill p.e. 1GB of physical RAM memory, no virtual memory, ramdisk, harddisk or so on. I tryed to hold the data on memory by a array, but the size written and used memory on RAM was looking different for me. But I agree, thats sounds possible for me for a better programmer than me.

Comment: `...but to an output of a few hundred random characters` And? The `</dev/zero head -c $((1024**3)) | tail` outputs 1024**3 zero bytes, you just don't see it. `sudo head` Why do you run head as root? Why do you run bash as root? `The follow one are looks not like a solution, because its manipulate the data` Why "manipulate the data" makes it not a solution?

Comment: when you say *`fill a certain amount of RAM`* are you referring to saving the data in a (`bash`) variable?

Comment: please update the question to clarify what you mean by *`random numbers`*? does this mean that you want to generate only the 10 digits `0-9`?

Comment: @markp-fuso , For me as an inexperienced programmer, holding data in a variable or in an array sounds like a good way to allocate a desired amount of memory. But there may well be other possibilities that I don't want to rule out. It is important that I can specify the amount of memory to be allocated, e.g. 1GB. Exactly which address areas of the RAM are used does not matter to me. And I change the headline to follow one: "How to fill a certain amount of RAM with the output of /dev/random" I hope thats make it more clear.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy, I change the headline to follow one: "How to fill a certain amount of RAM with the output of /dev/random" I hope thats make it more clear. –

Comment: @KamilCuk "...but to an output of a few hundred random characters And? The </dev/zero head -c $((1024**3)) | tail outputs 1024**3 zero bytes, you just don't see it." Thats intresting. THX.  You ask: sudo head Why do you run head as root? Why do you run bash as root? I am not a real programmer. Perhaps it dosnt need. "The follow one are looks not like a solution, because its manipulate the data Why "manipulate the data" makes it not a solution?" Remove "\0\n" sounds for me its manipulate the output from dev/random. In my case thats should be no problem.

Comment: So a rule of thumb: run without sudo everything you can, only use sudo if you must. Sudo gives admin access, allows a command to remove all your files.

Answer (score 7):

For sake of discussion:

- we will *`fill RAM`* by assigning a long string of data to a `bash` variable
- we will limit ourselves to 1 GB (1024^3) of data (increasing the size is doable but at some point we'll also need to take into consideration OS settings, in particular `ARG_MAX` which determines the max amount of data that can be assigned to a variable)
- since OP appears to be primarily interested in filling memory we will look at a couple options based on *a)* repeated characters (the single digit `0` as an example) and *b)* random data
- there are several caveats/issues that arise depending on the OS, OS settings, the type of data we're saving and how we're populating the variable; some of these issues will be covered in the latter portion of the answer
- system we'll be testing on: `Ubuntu 22.04`, `bash v.5.1.16(1)`, `i7-1260P`, `64 GB RAM`

Overall results:

```
Solution                     Time     Max Memory(*)   Notes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Appending `bash` variables   12 secs      1.3 GB      reduce memory overhead (smaller "t") at cost of taking longer to run
/dev/urandom (100%)          18 secs      2.0 GB
/dev/urandom (appending)     15 secs      1.3 GB      16x copies of 64 MB of random data

(*) - ignoring the additional 3.5-4 GB of memory required for: echo "${#x} / ${x:0:9} / ${x: -10}"
```

---

Solution: ***Appending `bash` variables***

The fastest solution I've found (so far) which also limits excessive memory usage:

```
$ cat fill_ram.1
#!/bin/bash

sleep 2                                           # allow time to grab initial memory usage

printf -v t "%0*d" $(( 64*1024*1024 )) 0          # populate variable "t" with 64 million 0's

echo "t(length) = ${#t}"                          # verify length of "t"

unset x

time for ((i=1;i<=16;i++)); do x+="${t}"; done    # populate variable "x" with 1 billion 0's

sleep 5

echo "x(length) = ${#x} / x(head) = ${x:0:9} / x(tail) = ${x: -10}"

sleep 2                                           # allow time to grab final memory usage
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./fill_ram.1
t(length) = 67108864

real    0m11.185s
user    0m6.448s
sys     0m4.735s

x(length) = 1073741824 / x(head) = 0000000000 / x(tail) = 0000000000
```

From this output we see that the variable `x` contains 1 GB (1073741824) of 0's.

While the script was running I had the following running in a separate console to capture total memory usage:

```
$ while true; do ps -eo size,command --sort -size | grep "[f]ill_ram"; sleep 0.1; done

  436 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1              # initial memory reading repeats for 2 secs until guts of script start
  436 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
  436 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
... snip ... 
65976 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
197052 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
328128 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
328128 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
262592 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
... snip ...
1245636 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
1311172 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
1311172 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
1114560 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
1114556 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
1114556 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1 
1114556 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1            # final memory reading repeats for 5 secs until the last "echo" ...
... snip ...
3211844 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1            # additional memory for echo / ${#x} / ${x:0:9} / ${x: -10}
... snip ...
5309000 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1            # additional memory for echo / ${#x} / ${x:0:9} / ${x: -10}
... snip ...
3211844 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1            # additional memory for echo / ${#x} / ${x:0:9} / ${x: -10}
... snip ...
5309000 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1            # additional memory for echo / ${#x} / ${x:0:9} / ${x: -10}
3211844 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1
1114688 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1            # final memory reading for 2 secs, after the last "echo" and before the script ends
1114688 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1
1114688 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.1
```

Of interest are the following details:

- memory usage jumps up-n-down until it reaches a steady state near the end
- max memory (sans the `echo`) actually tops out at 1280 MB (1311172) before settling at 1088 MB (1114556)
- keep in mind how follow-on operations against a 1 GB variable (eg, the `echo ${#x} / ${x:0:9) / ${x: -10}`) can further increase memory usage (in this case up to 5 GB), and on a system where memory is limited you could be looking at generating `OOM errors`
- the final/total memory usage of `1088 MB` breaks down into `64 MB` for variable `t` and `1024 MB` for variable `x`
- every time memory goes 'up' and then 'down', the drop is a multiple of 64 MB (the size of variable `t`) and represents a side effect of the operation `x+="${t}"`, ie, `bash` is briefly making copies of variable `t` (this *`side effect`* becomes quite noticeable in other solutions we'll look at later)
- the use of 64 MB for variable `t` was chosen to balance out *a)* the number of times we had to execute the `bash/for` loop, *b)* the (relatively) short period of time to populate variable `x` while *c)* limiting the extra memory usage for variable `t` (and the *`side effect`* memory usage)

---

Solution: ***/dev/urandom (100%)***

While the previous solution consisted of populating variable `x` with 1 billion 0's, here's one approach for populating variable `x` with 1 billion random characters:

- `bash` variables cannot store the `\0` character so we'll need to skip said character
- during testing I found that consuming *all* data coming from `/dev/urandom` tended to give me a lot more than the 1 billion characters I wanted; instead of trying to get `head -c` to work 'properly' I opted to limit the operation to printable characters

The code I ended up running:

```
$ cat fill_ram.2
#!/bin/bash

sleep 2

time x=$( tr -dc '[[:print:]]' < /dev/urandom | head -c $(( 1024**3 )) )

sleep 5

echo "x(length) = ${#x} / x(head) = ${x:0:9} / x(tail) = ${x: -10}"

sleep 2
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./fill_ram.2

real    0m17.607s
user    0m14.148s
sys     0m8.441s

x(length) = 1073741824 / x(head) = _d\rg(}Ah / x(tail) = A&Jk>7AkM!
```

From this output we see that variable `x` contains 1 GB (1073741824) of random data.

The `ps | grep` output for this run:

```
  436 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2              # initial memory reading repeats for 2 secs until guts of script start
  436 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2
  436 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2
... snip ... 
  568 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2              # parent script
 8228 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2              # tr|head subprocess
  568 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2              # parent script
16228 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2              # tr|head subprocess
  568 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2              # parent script
23440 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2              # tr|head subprocess
... snip ...
  568   /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # parent script
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # tr|head about to exit and data is copied to variable "x" in the parent script
2097776 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # this runs for a few seconds ...
2097776 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2
2097776 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2
... snip ...
2097776 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # until the copy finishes;
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # the tr|head exits and
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # we're left with just the
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # contents of variable "x"
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2
... snip ...
3146352 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # then several secs of memory increases to ...
5243508 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # support the last 
"echo"
... snip ...
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # and finally back to just
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # the memory for variable "x"
1049196 /bin/bash ./fill_ram.2            # until the script ends
```

Of interest are the following details:

- memory usage increases steadily as the `tr|head` subprocess generates 1 billion printable characters
- when the `tr|head` subprocess exits the resulting 1 GB of data is then copied into variable `x`, causing total memory usage to jump to 2 GB
- once the copy completes memory usage drops back down to 1 GB
- as we saw in the first solution, the last `echo` operation spikes memory usage up to 5 GB; again, in a tight-memory situation those variable references (`${#x} / ${x:0:9) / ${x: -10}`) could lead to `OOM errors`

---

Solution: ***/dev/urandom (appending)***

A merging of the previous two solutions:

- populate variable `t` with 1 MB of printable, random characters via a `tr|head` subprocess
- use a `bash/for` loop to build up variable `x`

Code for this solution:

```
$ cat fill_ram.3
#!/bin/bash

time t=$( tr -dc '[[:print:]]' < /dev/urandom | head -c $(( 64*1024*1024 )) ) 

echo "t(length) = ${#t}"

unset x

time for ((i=1;i<=16;i++)); do x+="${t}"; done

echo "x(length) = ${#x} / x(head) = ${x:0:9} / x(tail) = ${x: -10}"
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
real    0m1.146s                   # tr|head => variable "t"
user    0m0.995s
sys     0m0.516s

t(length) = 67108864

real    0m13.343s                  # for loop => variable "x"
user    0m7.892s
sys     0m4.681s

x(length) = 1073741824 / x(head) = bQZzP/y,K / x(tail) = w3gL<RP_(H
```

As with the `/dev/urandom (100%)` solution we see that variable `x` contains 1 GB (1073741824) of random data.

I won't bother (bore?) you with yet another dump of `ps/memory` output; the results were the same as with the `Appending bash variables` solution ... max memory topped out at 1.3 GB before settling at `1088 MB` (`64 MB` for variable `t` and `1024 MB` for variable `x`).

---

Additional details, in no particular order ...

**cygwin vs linux**

I originally started working in both environments - `cygwin` and `linux (Ubuntu 22.04)` - both running a version of `bash v.5.x`.

The `cygwin` environment is nowhere near as 'stable' as Ubuntu so I ended up having to jerry rig the solutions in `cygwin`. The `/dev/urandom' components were the most finicky.

I finally opted to focus on the `linux` environment.

The rest of these rambling details include some bits-n-pieces from the `cygwin` testing.  Additional `cygwin` bits-n-pieces can probably be salvaged from the answer's edit history.

**/dev/random vs /dev/urandom**

We'll use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`; see the following for more details:

- [When to use /dev/random vs /dev/urandom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209)
- [Differences between random and urandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712581)

**What characters to keep/discard?**

`bash` variables cannot store the `\0` character so initial attempts to populate variable `x` consisted of the following:

```
x=$( tr -d '\0' </dev/urandom | head -c $(( 1024**3 )) )
```

In my linux environment this caused `x` to be populated with 2 GB of data before the process hung (and had to be killed). (see `ARG_MAX` - below - for more details).

In my `cygwin` environment this caused the process to go walkabout (killed after a few minutes) while memory usage was jumping all over the place (277 MB, 653 MB, 327 MB, 603 MB, 221 MB, ....).

I quickly figured out I could address these issues by limiting data to printable characters hence:

```
x=$( tr -dc '[[:print:]]' < /dev/urandom | head -c $(( 1024**3 )) )    # linux
```

For the `cygwin` environment this wasn't quite acceptable since the `bash` process still went walkabout while memory usage was (still) jumping all over the place, so for `cygwin` I decided to reduce the initial data size to 1 MB (`1024**2`):

```
x=$( tr -dc '[[:print:]]' < /dev/urandom | head -c $(( 1024**2 )) )    # cygwin
```

And then expand the content in `x` by 1024-fold via a `bash/while` loop:

```
i=1024; while ((i>1)); do x+="$x"; ((i/=2)); done
```

**How many characters can we capture?**

As mentioned earlier the initial linux population of variable `x` hung once the number of bytes in `x` hit 2 GB; turns out this was a limitation of the OS configuration, in particular, I hit up against the `ARG_MAX` limit in my OS configuration:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

While it's possible to increase this setting, in this case it was a moot point since I only wanted to save 1 GB of data in variable `x`.

In the case of `cygwin`, who knows ...

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
undefined
```

I didn't investigate this any further since I was able to save 1 GB of data in variable `x` via the final solution (printable characters, grab 1MB from urandom, manually expand `x` by 1024-fold).

If you have problems stuffing 1 GB of data into a (`bash`) variable, or wish to go above 1 GB but run into issues, there are several tangents to investigate re: `ARG_MAX`; see the following for starters:

- [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642)
- [What is the maximum size of a linux environment variable value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031)

**How to verify the amount of memory used?**

How to measure memory usage will depend on the OS, the tools available within said OS, and the software you're using (`bash` in this case).

Knowing the size of the data in the variable (`bash / ${#x}`; other software may have profiling tools that can provide this info) should be sufficient to prove that memory is in use, but if you want to verify it at the OS level then there are slew of ways to go about this.

In the case of my linux environment I opted for `ps -o`, while in my `cygwin` environment I went the easy/lazy route and just grabbed some snapshots from Windows' Task Manager (and because `cygwin's` `ps` implementation does not support the `-o` option).

For additional ideas on how to measure memory:

- web search on phrases like *`bash process memory usage`* and *`bash memory used by variables`*
- [How can I measure the actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303)

**Filling more than 1 GB of memory**

What if you want to fill up more than 1 GB of memory?

With `${#x}` == `1073741824` you'd think you'd be safe with something as simple as one of the following:

```
x+="${x}"          # double the size of variable "x"

y="${x}"           # copy variable "x" into variable "y"
```

But in both cases I'm presented with the following `OOM error`:

```
./testme: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562068096 bytes
```

To be honest, I haven't (so far) been able to track down a satisfactory explanation for this occurrence.  Even with the `side effect memory` (ie, making copies of variable `x`) doubled or tripled we're only talking about a spike up to 3-5 GB of total memory usage ... not enough to cause an `OOM error` on a machine with 64 GB of RAM, and nowhere near the 18 quintillion (?) bytes the `OOM error` is referencing.

In the meantime I have verified that both *appending* solutions do allow for the creation of larger variables (eg, 2 GB, 3 GB) by simply increasing the number of times we execute the `for` loop.

Obviously (?) at some point larger volumes of data could run into `ARG_MAX` values but then you could look at populating another variable.

Answer (score 3):

> how can you similarly fill a given amount of memory, e.g. 1GB, with random numbers?

`tail` outputs on *lines*. So remove newlines.

```
</dev/urandom tr -d '\n' | head -c $((1024**3)) | tail >/dev/null
```

> The follow one are looks not like a solution,

If you want *not similarly* fill a given amount of memory *and keep it filled*, you can indeed store it in bash. Because command substitution removes trailing newlines and you can't store zero bytes, I would remove both.

```
var=$(</dev/urandom tr -d '\0\n' | head -c $((1024**3)) )
```

Fun fact: `echo ${#var}` might not be accurate without `LC_ALL=C`.

Also, on most systems `/tmp` or better `/dev/shm` is just `tmpfs`, which can be confirmed with `mount` or `findmnt`. You could also do `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/shm/some_random_file_name bs=1024 count=3 status=none` or really just `head -c $((1024**3)) /dev/urandom > /dev/shm/some_random_file_name` to fill the memory.

Comment: @KamiCuk, "var=$(</dev/random tr -d '\0\n' | head -c $((1024**3)) )" That's perfect, or at least almost perfect. I'll have to think about it a bit. In any case, it is very usable for my specific application as it is. Thank you.

Comment: `/dev/random` is going to be very slow for this, as you will be depleting the kernel's randomness source. If you can accept some (theoretical) predictability in the random data, use `/dev/urandom` instead.

Comment: @Tripleee It's exactly the opposite of what you wrote.

Comment: Huh? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom

Comment: @KamiCuk THX for your Bounty winning answer. If you replace urandom by random, I also can mark as solution. I cant edit by self, I would need to change 6 caracters at minimum. "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Comment: `If you replace urandom by random` Triplee posted a link that urandom should be preferred "Use /dev/urandom for most practical purposes" "Use /dev/urandom" "Don't use /dev/random" "/dev/random has been deprecated for a decade". The link is quite convincing.